# Use dynamic type implementations in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I created a typescript module that have type definitions and js implementations in the dist folder. That typescript module is used as an npm package dependency hosted on an internal HTTP link. Here is the current architecture in a stupid looking diagram.

[image]

I have a requirement to make the js implementation of the typecript module dynamic so that the angular app does not need to be rebuilt when something changes in the external module implementation (unless the change involves type changes). Here is what I want the architecture to look like:
[image]

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [NX Dev Tools](https://nx.dev/). It is very useful for building a monorepo architecture and should meet your requirements. It works for Angular and other frameworks and has a great CLI, as Angular itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although I feel this should be supported OOTB. I should not really require another plugin to support something like this. Trying to stay away from new deps.

Comment: OK, I can understand that. There is an increase in complexity and the need for dependencies. Maybe you could have a look into [Yarn Workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/) - the only "dependency" is yarn.

Comment: ..this is a great [article](https://dev.to/t7yang/typescript-yarn-workspace-monorepo-1pao) on the topic